# Javascript 3d Graphing utility?

Tags: javascript, graph

Does any one know of any good javascript 3d graphing utility? I know that every site ever recommends [Canvas 3d Graph](http://dragan.yourtree.org/blog/en/2007/08/05/canvas-3d-graph/) but it is actually quite limiting. For one it only allows graphing with datasets that are within the 1000. Though it does have some capability (with a bit of code modifying) to graph data that are a bit out of its range, nothing out of a complete revamp will allow graphing of data based on time or with values hugely larger than 1000. (I have data values that range into the billions.)

Or should I abandon all hope and either write one myself or look to other technology?

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380316/what-is-the-best-online-resource-for-3d-rendering-in-javascript) StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google O3D is a library for producing 3d-graphics using Javascript. It also has a deprecated plugin, but the newest version uses WebGL.

Check it out here: http://code.google.com/p/o3d/

You'll definitely need to build a small graphing-shell around it, but it shouldn't be hard, especially not if you look closely to the examples provided on the Google-code website.

It uses OpenGL as a backend-technology: rendering lots of polygons, on reasonable hardware, is not a problem at all.

Comment: This sounds awesome! I wouldn't mind using OpenGL as well, though most likely javascript is sufficient, the graphing is a relatively insignificant part of what I'm doing so no need to spend too much resources on it. Saying that, this sounds pretty cool.

Also, I love how your rep is 3333