# Treemap in 3D graph library

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, 3d

I'm searching graph related **Treemap in 3D**.

I searched some **free / paid** popular graph library but those are not satisfied with my requirement. I attached graph image which i'm finding.

[image]

[image]

I already searched these libraries but they don't provide 3D in Treemap.

- [philogb](http://philogb.github.io)
- [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com)
- [nvd3](http://nvd3.org/)
- [amcharts](http://www.jqplot.com)
- [jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com)
- [anycharts](http://www.anychart.com)

Please suggest some graph library that fulfill my requirement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript 3d Graphing utility?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122165/javascript-3d-graphing-utility)

Comment: I am not sure about any 3d charting library in javascript but something like [this](http://makc3d.wordpress.com/2013/10/30/using-d3-js-with-three-js/) may help.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your requirements, or how you'd use the third dimension? It seems like you're looking for a [2D tree map](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582) to which you can apply a [3D contour plot](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_terrain) from separate data, with (sprite-based?) overlays. As slashdottir mentioned, you'll want to look at [three.js](http://threejs.org/).

Comment: yes threejs is fine for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you be more specific about what your requirement is?

Have you looked at [three.js](http://threejs.org/)

They don't have an explicit data structure mapper, but maybe you could create your treemap, then use it as a texture on a surface and then change the camera angle.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most complete collections of javascript libraries for visualizing graphs is [here](http://techslides.com/50-javascript-charting-and-graphics-libraries/).

Maybe there you'll find what you need.

From your picture, this could be the library you are searching for:

http://d3js.org/

[Here](http://cesiumjs.org/demos/d3.html) is an example, that looks quite the same:

[image]