# Magento custom product design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magento

I have a magento store where we want the customer to design his own furniture. Is there a way that whenever he select a texture or a color, a request is sent to the server which returns about 8 images(each representing a part of the furniture) to display the full image and have a 360 degree view of the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento doesn't have such functionality out of the box so you will have to write it yourself.

You could use [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) for 3D canvas rendering but WebGL is not supported by IE as you can see from [this](http://caniuse.com/webgl) compatibility matrix.

You should also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380316/what-is-the-best-online-resource-for-3d-rendering-in-javascript) SO question - accepted answer contains a list of 3D rendering samples (at least some of them work in IE as well).

You will also have to implement a controller that would get called over ajax and send images for rendering back to the page.